# Changes list all files as added instead of only last commit modification

Tags: jenkins

Using Jenkins 2.108, the Changes summary is now wrong.

It list only the last commit (even if there were several since last build) and it list all files of the project as added.

Any idea?

Comment: Did this happen when using Multibranch Pipeline plugin?

Comment: That's right, I use Multibranch Pipeline plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As reported in [JENKINS-45586](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45586) this issue can occur if you are using GIT shallow clone option.

As a workaround, you can set the depth to 2 if you run a Jenkins build for every commit as explained in [JENKINS-45586#comment-331463](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45586?focusedCommentId=331463&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-331463). To be safe you can set it to a number like 5.

Comment: that may have helped. I'm so disappointed to have missed this answer. now I must go see Stackoverflow settings